# SQL User Defined Function Within Select - Again

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Firstly apologies - I know there are numerous threads on this subject however I can't find an answer to my question.

I have a UDF to work out business days between two dates. I am using SQL Server 2008.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CountWeekDays
(
    @fromdate Datetime,
    @todate Datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
(

SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @fromdate, @todate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @fromdate, @todate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @fromdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @todate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  As NoOfWeekDays

)
```

I am trying to call it in a select statement along with another table:

```
select dbo.fn_CountWeekDays(a.date1,a.date2) as workdays
from alex_datetest a
```

However I am getting the error:

Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fn_CountWeekDays", or the name is ambiguous.

If I drop the dbo. then I get this:

'fn_CountWeekDays' is not a recognized function name.

Does anyone have any ideas why I can't reference this function?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Comment: Your function returns a table, but you're referencing it as if it returned a scalar value.

Comment: You are using table value function, all you need it to change the RETURN to the datatype you want to use, for you it will be int

Answer (score 1):

As I put in the comment, alter your function to be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_CountWeekDays
(
    @fromdate Datetime,
    @todate Datetime
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN DECLARE @int int

SET @int = 
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @fromdate, @todate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @fromdate, @todate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @fromdate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @todate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);

  RETURN @int
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a table valued function, so you want to use `apply`:

```
select cwd.*
from alex_datetest a cross apply 
     dbo.fn_CountWeekDays(a.date1,a.date2) cwd
```

If you want to name the column:

```
select cwd.workdays
from alex_datetest a cross apply 
     dbo.fn_CountWeekDays(a.date1,a.date2) cwd(workdays)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is returning table you might require to use cross apply as below:

```
Select * from yourtable a
   cross apply dbo.fn_CountWeekDays(a.date1,a.date2) f
```

Comment: Thank you so much - Works perfectly. I've been puzzling over this for hours